# Go to another page the password is correct in php

Tags: php, html, passwords

I am developing an application in php and html in which the user must enter a number in the input. however if the number is 1 to press the button opens another page, but if the number is different does not open anything. The code i'm using is as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RHM</title> 
      <style type="text/css">
    h1 { color: red; font-family: arial; font-size: 3em; font-weight:   bolder; }
    p { color: navy; font-family: Verdana; }
   </style>
  </head>
 <body>
   <h1 align="center">INGRESE CONTRASE&Ntilde;A</h1>
     <form  action="#" method="post" >
   <p align="center"> <input type="password" name="contras" style="width:200px;height:50px;background-color:yellow;color:blue;font-size:14pt;font-family: Comic Sans MS;text-align:center;padding-right:10px;"/></p>
   <p align="center"  ><input type="submit" value="Entrar" /></p>
<?
  $Contraseña=$_POST['contras'];
   if ($Contraseña==1) {
     action=="Decidir.php";
  }
?>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

So far as this does nothing. please help thank you all.

Comment: replace `action=="Decidir.php";` with `header('Location: '/decidir.php')`

Comment: Did the replacement. Does nothing.

Comment: Oh, I forgot, you need to move your PHP code at the top of the page, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Plus, you have asked 21 questions so far, but gave no answer to any of them. Which is why the last used removed his/her answers. Give credit to other people's help.

Comment: specifically where it goes php code ?

Comment: Here, just copy/past this. http://pastebin.com/KnMA7YeU good luck

Comment: No open the link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
....
<?
 $Contraseña=$_POST['contras'];
   if ($Contraseña==10836053) {
     header("Location: Decidir.php");
  }
?>
</form>
```

Thank sam_io.